# Update text box value only on button click

Tags: angular

I How can I display the text box value only on the click of a button? Below in the code snippet..

HTML:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="serverName">
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddClk">Add</button>
```

TS File:

```
onAddClk(){

}
```

How do I access my ngModel from TS file, so that on button click i can see the content of my text box?

Comment: you can  access the value of  textbox using ``this.serverName `` .

Answer (score 0):

As simple as that. If its a component property then you have to access it using `this` operator.

```
onAddClk() {
    console.log(this.serverName);
}
```

By the way Welcome to Angular2!!
 https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can add a flag with `*ngIf` and set it to `true` when `button` is clicked.

```
<div>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="serverName">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddClk()">Add</button>
      <div *ngIf="showServerName">{{serverName}}</div>
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
serverName;
showServerName = false;

onAddClk(){
  alert("Server Name: " + this.serverName); 
  this.showServerName = true;
}
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ULjeKzSqCpftPSiRIaJH?p=preview)